# fireEvent.keyDown not working as expected on my Jest + React Testing Library test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

In my current React project, I'm testing a component which includes, as child component, the [Dialog component from Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/).

It's supposed it has to run the `onClose()` function when the user presses the `Esc` key. I tested it manually and it works perfectly well. Now I'm doing the same test, this time using **Jest + React Testing Library**. You can see the code below:

```
fireEvent.keyDown(container, {
      key: "Escape",
      code: "Escape",
      keyCode: 27,
      charCode: 27
    });
```

And the test doesn't pass. After some debugs, I've realized that the event is actually being triggered, but for some reason is not having an impact on the `<Dialog/>` component.

So I did run the component on Google Chrome, and triggered the same event from the Dev Tools console with the following code:

```
document.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent(
        "keydown", {     
            key: "Escape",
            code: "Escape",
            keyCode: 27,
            charCode: 27
        }
    )
);
```

...and it doesn't work either.

What can I do to make this test pass?

Comment: What is `container`? In the test you are firing the event on the `container`, but this may not be the case when using the app in the browser.

Comment: The container is the wrapper component. But in the case of Material UI Dialog, the Escape key should work, no matter where is the focus

Comment: Can you provide a Code Sandbox ?

Comment: @JMadelaine you were right. The problem was the target of the event

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The user JMadelaine was right, and I've found what was wrong. The event target shouldn't be the `container` nor `document`, but the dialog box itself. So now I've changed the code from this:

```
fireEvent.keyDown(container, {
      key: "Escape",
      code: "Escape",
      keyCode: 27,
      charCode: 27
});
```

...to this:

```
fireEvent.keyDown(getByText(/the text in the dialog box/i), {
      key: "Escape",
      code: "Escape",
      keyCode: 27,
      charCode: 27
});
```

And it works.

Comment: Not working for me, but also you may want to add `await` to the `fireEvent`

Comment: @Justin this failed for me as well initially.
Changing keyCode and charCode to number instead of a string worked for me....

Comment: Related: simple utility to see keycode info: https://justingolden.me/keycode/ (some are only supported in older browsers and some in newer browsers. Check caniuse)

Comment: Legend this solved my issue! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  it('calls setShowModal on escape key', () => {
    render(<ModalPopUp {...props}>children</ModalPopUp>)
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Escape' })
    document.dispatchEvent(event)
    expect(props.setShowModal).toBeCalled()
  })
```